# How to make a class to store static colors?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried doing this to make all colors stay inside the Color class just so they have a namespace:

```
class Color {
  const Color currentSection = const Color(0x626262);
  const Color aBackground = const Color(0xE5E5E5);
  const Color aSidebar = const Color(0x7C01FF);
  const Color aSoundButton = const Color(0xA93EF0);
  const Color aSoundLockedButton = const Color(0x555555);
  const Color aSoundButtonText = const Color(0xFFFFFF);
}
```

but I get erros at const: `Const variables must be initialized with a constant value.`

How can I make a class just as a container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: Use `static const` 
Step 2: You lost two character, you can change `0x626262` to `0x62626200`, when use with `Android Studio`, you can see color if definition is correct 
You can also reference source code of `colors.dart` https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/d8167b90e26038b4290331e555211e781e0cddea/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/colors.dart#L198 
code snippet

```
class CustomColors {
  static const Color currentSection = Color(0x62626200);
  static const Color aBackground = Color(0xE5E5E500);
  static const Color aSidebar = Color(0x7C01FF00);
  static const Color aSoundButton = Color(0xA93EF000);
  static const Color aSoundLockedButton = Color(0x55555500);
  static const Color aSoundButtonText = Color(0xFFFFFF00);
}
```

[image]

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomColors {
  static const Color currentSection = Color(0x62626200);
  static const Color aBackground = Color(0xE5E5E500);
  static const Color aSidebar = Color(0x7C01FF00);
  static const Color aSoundButton = Color(0xA93EF000);
  static const Color aSoundLockedButton = Color(0x55555500);
  static const Color aSoundButtonText = Color(0xFFFFFF00);
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(       
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {     
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(        
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(        
        child: Column(          
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(width: 100, height: 100,color: CustomColors.aSoundLockedButton),
            Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: CustomColors.aSoundButton),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of your `Color` class to something like `MyColor`. You're trying to construct Dart/Flutter `Color` objects, but you have created a naming collision. It is trying to construct objects from your `Color` class, which has no constant constructor, causing the error. Also, add `static` before `const` for your declarations.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Colors {
 static Color currentSection =  Color(0xff626262);
 static Color aBackground =  Color(0xffE5E5E5);
 static Color aSidebar =  Color(0xff7C01FF);
 static Color aSoundButton =  Color(0xffA93EF0);
 static Color aSoundLockedButton =  Color(0xff555555);
 static Color aSoundButtonText =  Color(0xffFFFFFF);
}
```

try like this.